# Go, go_appengine, and agouti - how?

Tags: google-app-engine, ginkgo, agouti

I'm building a small app in Go running on Google Appengine. I've got it running locally, with tests using aetest. Works great.

I'd like to add BDD tests using Agouti. What I'm trying to understand is how Agouti can work with aetest. My Agouti tests will start the aetest instance, but I can't figure out how a) how to figure out which port the test devserver is running on (aetest.Instance has a method url() which appears to indicate this, but that method isn't exported), and b) how to tell Agouti the port.

Am I thinking about this wrong? I'd love to have the BeforeSuite or BeforeEach block set up the environment, but if there's another approach, I'd love to hear it.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post some code to gett better answers.